# The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted (IE only)

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, c#-4.0, jquery, viewstate

I've see all of the other pages with this questions, but no amount of research has solved my problem.  I am getting the "The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted" error.  My page loads fine the first time.  The page contains a div that has tabs that change the info on the page and the tabs are loaded dynamically and are linked to a different page.  The tabing uses jquery.  Without changing anything on the page, when I try to reload this page by click on the link that gets to this page or even by clicking on ANY link in the menu bar that goes to other pages, I this error.  Again, this only happens in IE and I've put break points all over my code and it never goes back to the server.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Templates/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="Reporting.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pegged.Reporting" Title="Workforce Planning Report" %>

<%@ Register Src="Controls/ucWebPageNavigation.ascx" TagName="ucWebPageNavigation"
    TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            ajaxOptions: {
                error: function (xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                    $(anchor.hash).html(
                        "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div id="IconLinks" class="TopLinks">
        <uc1:ucWebPageNavigation ID="ucWebPageNavigation1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div id="divContainerReport" class="container_12">
        <!--Facility Tabs-->
        <div id="tabs">
        <ul id="FacilityTabs" runat="server" ></ul></div>
        </div>

</asp:Content>
```

This is the code that loads the tabs on page load:

```
ServicesDLL.Services ps = new ServicesDLL.Services();
string encryptString = "";
string encryptString2 = "";

encryptString = ps.EncryptQueryString("Test");
encryptString2 = ps.EncryptQueryString("Testing");
string innerhtml = "<li><a id=\"id1\" href=\"ReportFacility.aspx?facility=" + encryptString + "\">Test</a></li><li><a id=\"id2\" href=\"ReportFacility.aspx?facility=" + encryptString2 + "\">Testing</a></li>";
FacilityTabs.InnerHtml = innerhtml;
```

And this is the page the tabs load:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Templates/Popup.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReportFacility.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pegged.ReportFacility" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div id="divReportView" class="grid_8 BlueBorder">
<p id="testText" runat="server"></p>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: try two thinks. place a literal inside the <ul id="FacilityTabs" runat="server" ></ul> and render on this literal and remove the runat=server from ul. Second add viewstate=false on this ul (or on the literal)

Comment: Are you running in a clustered web environment?

Comment: @Aristos, can you give me an example of that please? And Eric, no.